# Canvas is working on TBB 8.0 with privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Canvas works even if privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts is enabled on TBB 8.0, is that normal ?

You can test with this. https://smashcat.org/av/canvas_test/

Answer (score 0):

If you configure "privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts" to "false" you improve your privacy disabling the automatically inputs don´t requested by user of canvas and do not disable it itself, that is, canvas keeps rolling with reduced chances of fingerprint analysis. The cost of disable is the drop of canvas performance, you can see this in the same test you posted:

Canvas auto input enable (Better performance option):
[image]

Canvas auto input disable (Better privacy option):
[image]

With the auto-input disabled the web page always asks if you want to activate it:

[image]

Comment: With privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts set to true, I get >200 fps in that same canvas test (smashcat.org).